# json/js/html quiz: how can I parse json data into a for loop and if statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a json file:

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "title": "01. q1",
      "type": "dropdown",
      "options": [
        {
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "q2",
      "type": "multiple_choice",
      "options": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5"
      ]
    },
```

And I'm trying to write a for loop in a js file in order to go through the data, and if the question type is "dropdown", display an html dropdown selectors, "multiple choice" would get buttons, etc:

```
console.log = function(message) {
    document.getElementById('q_1').innerHTML = message;
};

console.log2 = function(message) {
    document.getElementById('q_2').innerHTML = message;
};

$.getJSON("generated.json", function(json)) {
  for (var i = 0; i<json.questions.length; i++) {
    if(json.questions[i].type=="drop_down") {

    }
  }
}
```

I'm really confused as to how to do this dynamically and not hard code most of the code. Is there a way for this to be written concisely without having to write out every option/question in an html file and just read and generate questions from the json file?

Comment: `function(json))` <-- remove the 2nd `)` and put it after the final `}`.  Other than that it looks fine.  Incidentally, did you really want to override the console log method??

Comment: Also try not to mix DOM JS and jQuery. It makes it even more confusing

Comment: Maybe document.createElement can help you

Answer (score 0):

this is the way you can use it :

```js
var data = [
    {
      "title": "01. q1",
      "type": "dropdown",
      "options": ["1","2","3"]
    },
    {
      "title": "q2",
      "type": "multiple_choice",
      "options": ["1","2","3","4","5"]
    }
];
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hello").append("<p>hello</p>")
    var s ="" ; 
    for(var i=0;i<data.length ; i++){
      if(data[i].type == "dropdown"){
        s += "<p>dropdown</p>";
        
      }
      else if(data[i].type == "multiple_choice"){
        s += "<p>multiple_choice</p>"
      }
    }
    
    $(".hello").append(s);
    
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hello">

</div>
```